# PhP Array how to get a value of a key

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a php array, $vararray, like so

```
[var1] => 1
[var2] => 1
[var3] => 1
[var4] => 1
[var5] => 2
[var6] => 2
[var7] => 1
[var8] => 1
```

After a bunch of operations i get a key/index of var8. How do I get value of var8 using the key? I can get the key using array key function. But is there a function for array value? I checked php manual but didnt seem to find any.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php -- PHP foreach?

Comment: `$value = $vararray['var8'];`?

Comment: Either you're not describing what you want very well, or you have no idea how to access arrays, since this is the basic way that arrays are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$key` contains the key you're interested in (e.g. `var8`) you use

```
$vararray[$key]
```

to access the value of the corresponding element.

Comment: Hey man thanks. Kinda  new at this stufff.. Also, thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this:

```
$value = $vararray['var8'];
```

Or you can loop over the array using a `foreach` loop: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach ($vararray as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessible like this

```
$var8Value = $vararray['var8'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting all keys value like `$var1`, `$var2`, `$var3`, .... Try this

```
foreach($vararray as $key=>$val){
    $$key = $val;
}
echo $var1;
echo $var2;
echo $var3;
echo $var4;
echo $var5;
echo $var6;
echo $var7;
echo $var8;
```